# Error establishing a database connection in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I have searched around and tried all other fixes found on StackOverflow and other places, such as changing the database and password but it is not working.

Here is `wp-config.php` code:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'shriyant_12345');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '******')
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Comment: What is the full error message you are receiving? This little bit of information tells us nothing.

Comment: this is the all error sir , when i am trying to open my website only showing this error

Comment: You may need to check the server error logs. Check with your web host if you're not sure where to find them.